# Where do I find Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.dll?

Tags: wix

I am trying to write an extension for Wix by subclassing CompilerExtension but I can't locate the dll to reference the Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml namespace. I searched on the web with no luck.

Any ideas where this can be found?

Mark

Comment: As the answer points out, you are confusing assemblies, DLLs and namespaces. You don't "reference" a namespace, though you can "use"/"import"/"open" a namespace; Types in an assembly can be in one or more (counting `global`) namespaces; Types in the same namespace can be in one or more assemblies. DLL names do not necessarily have any bearing on namespaces. A .NET assembly is one or more netmodules, exactly one of which contains a .NET manifest, plus zero or more external files (not netmodules). The typical case is an assembly consisting of one file with a .DLL or .EXE extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.CompilerExtension` is in the assembly `wix.dll` (there is no assembly/DLL named `Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.dll`). The assembly is located in `<wixinstalldir>\bin` (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.6\bin\wix.dll`).

You might also want to have a look at the [WixContrib project](http://wixcontrib.codeplex.com/) at Codeplex.