# Light.exe error LGHT0307 'Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.AssemblyDefaultWixExtensionAttribute' was not defined in the assembly

Tags: wix

I am creating a batch file using wix light and candle to create an msi for a project.

I am receiving this error when i run the batch file:

> light.exe : error LGHT0307 : Either
>   'Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.AssemblyDefaultWixExtensionAttribute'
>   was not defined in the assembly or the type defined in extension
>   'C:\Users\User1\Documents\testProj\CustomAction\bin\Debug\CustomAction.dll'
>   could not be loaded.

I have checked the filepath of the CustomAction.dll and verified it is correct. I have added the CustomAction.dll extension to the light command. I am running this batch file from the windows command line in administrator mode.

> Batch File
>
> ----Line 1-----
>
> "%WIX%bin\candle" *.wxs
>   -dCustomAction.TargetDir="C:\Users\User1\Documents\testProj\CustomAction\bin\Debug\"
>   -o obj\Debug\
>
> ----Line 2----------
>
> "%WIX%bin\light" obj\Debug*.wixobj -ext
>   "C:\Users\User1\Documents\testProj\CustomAction\bin\Debug\CustomAction.dll"
>   -ext "C:\Users\User1\Documents\testProj\CustomAction\bin\Debug\CustomAction.CA.dll"
>   -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixUIExtension.dll" -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin" -ext WixIIsExtension -ext WixNetFxExtension -ext WixUIExtension -ext
>   WixUtilExtension -ext
>   "C:\Users\User1\Documents\testProj\Utils\bin\Debug\Utils.dll" -o
>   obj\Debug\CommandLineInstaller.msi

I expect this to properly generate an msi file but i am receiving error `code error LGHT0307`.

I have removed CustomActino.dll and CustomAction.CA.dll from the candle command line. I have removed C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixUIExtension.dll and included -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin" to the light command. Currently i am receiving this error " light.exe : error LGHT0144 : The extension 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin' could not be loaded because of the following reason: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied."

Here is the new command line: 
"%WIX%bin\light" obj\Debug*.wixobj -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin" -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixUIExtension.dll" -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin" -ext WixIIsExtension -ext WixNetFxExtension -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixUtilExtension -ext "C:\Users\User1\Documents\testProj\Utils\bin\Debug\Utils.dll" -o obj\Debug\CommandLineInstaller.msi

Comment: [Please check if the fix in section two here works for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777376/129130). Essentially: remove the project reference to **`Wix.dll`**. On second read that is probably something else, leaving this in still.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Custom Action DLLs***: I think you might need to take out the **`CustomAction.dll`** entry in the **`light.exe`** command line. Maybe take out all entries and add back one entry at a time. See sample command lines below.
>
> - **`CustomAction.dll`** - Managed Code assembly dll
> - **`CustomAction.CA.dll`** - Win32 wrapper dll for managed code dll:**`CustomAction.dll`**

***MakeSfxCA.exe***: The latter one is what you should include in your MSI. The DTF ([Deployment Tools Foundation](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2008/5/16/deployment-tools-foundation-joins-the-wix-toolset/)) tool [**`MakeSfxCA.exe`**](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/events-and-actions/how-to-manage/) creates this .CA version of your managed DLL. It contains all the necessary config files for your managed dll to run. You can open **`CustomAction.CA.dll`** with 7Zip or another, capable compression program to see the content.

***Batch Build***: [Minimal command line to build WiX project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481391/129130) (if you use a default WiX GUI) - and [how-to make a simple WiX project in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47972615/129130):

```
 candle.exe product.wxs -ext WixUIExtension
 light.exe -out Test.msi product.wixobj -ext WixUIExtension
```

***Votive***: I suppose you could try to build the WiX project in Visual Studio to see what command lines are used for **`candle.exe`** and **`light.exe`** in the built output window. That should give you a clue what might not be necessary (I suppose that might be what you already did):

[image: Output]

---

***Links***:

- [Please see this similar, but slightly different issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777376/129130)

Comment: I have removed the CustomAction.dll and CustomAction.dll from the light.exe command line. Now i am getting an errr LGHT 0144  The extension 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin' could not be loaded because of the following reason: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied. I have also tried to run the candle and light command lines visual studios creates and based my candle and light command lines off of it.

Comment: Maybe update question with new command line? I take it you haven't added ``"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\`` to the path? You could temporarily try that. And then remove ``-ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixUIExtension.dll"``.

Comment: Most people use MSBuild - I believe - to build via the command line like that. [There is a section on using MSBuild in the WiX help material](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/). Hold on a second and I will create a better sample using regular batch files though.

Answer (score 0):

> ***MSBuild***: Most people use MSBuild - I believe - to build via the command line like that. [There is a section on using MSBuild in the WiX help material](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/).

---

***Custom Action DLL***: I include custom action DLLs from within the WiX source file. Here is a sample with hard coded paths in the WiX source file for how you can include your custom action dll:

> The construct: **`$(env.SystemRoot)`** - in the WiX source below -
> gets the environment variable **`%SystemRoot%`** - which resolves to
> `C:\` on most systems (to list environment variables open a `cmd.exe`
> and type `set` and press `Enter`). The below source should hence
> compile on all systems without modifications:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="SimpleCustomAction" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0"
           Manufacturer="-" UpgradeCode="">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />    
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SimpleCustomAction" Level="1" />

<!-- START: Custom action entries -->
    
    <!-- Hard coded SourceFile path to compiled C# dll Win32 wrapper (MakeSfxCA.exe) -->
    <Binary Id="CustomActions" SourceFile="C:\CustomAction1.CA.dll" /> 

    <!-- BinaryKey => Use Binary element Id from above entry-->
    <!-- DllEntry => Exported method name inside dll (C# method name) -->
    <CustomAction Id="SimpleCustomAction" BinaryKey="CustomActions" DllEntry="CustomAction1"/>
    
    <!-- Run custom action -->
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="SimpleCustomAction" After="CostFinalize" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
    
<!-- END: Custom action entries -->    

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SimpleCustomAction">
          <Component Feature="ProductFeature">
            <File Source="$(env.SystemRoot)\notepad.exe" />
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

  </Product>
</Wix>
```

***Batch Build***: This should suffice, no need to specify anything in the **`candle.exe`** and **`light.exe`** commands to build the MSI. Here are some sample commands:

```
"%WIX%bin\candle.exe" product.wxs -ext WixUIExtension >> Build.log
"%WIX%bin\light.exe" -out Test.msi product.wixobj -ext WixUIExtension >> Build.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the new suggestion. However it appears as though my prodct.wxs does have a hard coded path to the custom.ca.dll and runs the custom action.            <Binary Id="CustomActionDll" SourceFile="$(var.CustomAction.TargetDir)CustomAction.CA.dll" />                                                                                  <InstallExecuteSequence><Custom Action="LoadConfigCA" Before="InstallFinalize" >NOT Installed</Custom></InstallExecuteSequence>

Comment: This is just a sample of a WiX project that should compile with that batch file. Maybe try to compile that first to see if you can get a "heartbeat" as I call it. Then take it from there?