# Connect WixUtilExtension dll to Wix project

Tags: wix, connection, wix3.11

I have wix toolset v3.11.
First, I add a link to the WixUtilExtension file in the bin folder. After I add namespase `xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"`
After building the project, I get the following errors:

```
The localization variable! (Loc.msierrUSRFailedUserCreate) is unknown. Please ensure the variable is defined

The localization variable! (Loc.msierrUSRFailedUserCreatePswd) is unknown. Please ensure the variable is defined.

The localization variable! (Loc.msierrUSRFailedUserGroupAdd) is unknown. Please ensure the variable is defined.
```

I tried to add the missing variables to the input files in the `SDK/wixui` and `SDK/themes` folders, but no effect, the errors did not disappear anywhere. Please help with the problem

Comment: Have you installed the Visual Studio integration packages in addition to the WiX toolkit? https://wixtoolset.org/releases/

Comment: Give us your whole source so we can see what is up. Github.com?

Comment: Did you pass `-ext WixUtilExtension` to candle and light both, or author it in as an extension in your MSBuild project? More information like that is needed.

Comment: [Please check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777376/129130) (don't add reference to wix.dll). Also see [the two answers for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58141164/129130). How to compile manually as opposed to via Visual Studio. Also make sure you have .NET 3.5 installed - if you are using WiX3.

Comment: @Stein Åsmul Thank you very much for your answer. I have .NET version 3.5 installed, I installed the Visual Studio integration packages. I have links to WixUIExtension and WixUtilExtension and the option with removing links does not work. I have not tried the command line option yet, I still wanted to do everything using VisualStudio.
In the link that you dropped, there was a suggestion to add a license file. I added this line, but errors still occur

Comment: Create a new project without localization to see if that builds. Or download a simple, sample project. For example [**this one**](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/VBScriptWriteToLog.zip). Just click ***`"Download"`***, unzip and open and try to compile.

Comment: @Stein Åsmul, Yes, the problem is most likely localization. In the current project, the Russian language is required, now I have created absolutely the same, but without setting the language and everything works without errors.
I also see that you are well versed in this topic :) I wanted to clarify one more thing, can you clarify in this discussion or create a new one?

Comment: I am heading out right now, you can find [a previous localization answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49605354/129130). Also have a look in github.com repositories for samples. Here is a ["canned search"](https://github.com/search?q=extension%3Awxs+ru-RU+SummaryCodepage%3D&type=Code). The general rule is to always create new questions for specific issues - so answers can be upvoted and identified as the helpful ones - and to allow people to easily find the problem they seek answers to.