# Where is 'Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper' for WiX

Tags: c#, wix, bootstrapper

I am learning to build a custom bootstrapper for Wix Bundle without using Visual Studio.
I tried to compile the following code section extracted from an example in the book "WiX3.6: A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML":

```
using Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper;
using System;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace CustomBA
{
   public class CustomBootstrapperApplication :
   BootstrapperApplication
   {
      public static Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; set; }
      protected override void Run()
      {
         Dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
         this.Engine.Detect();
         Dispatcher.Run();
      }
   }
}
```

The following compilation errors were encountered:

##### csc /r:wix.dll /r:WindowsBase.dll customba.cs

customba.cs(1,43): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Bootstrapper' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml'
(are you missing an assembly reference?)
customba.cs(8,4): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BootstrapperApplication' could not be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

wix.dll was copied from the WIX toolset directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin" as I found an answer in the StackOverflow Q&A:
[Where do I find Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717073/where-do-i-find-microsoft-tools-windowsinstallerxml-dll)

When I use ildasm to view the wix.dll, indeed I cannot find "Bootstrapper" namespace in 'Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml'.
Please advise where can I find Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper and BootstrapperApplication?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.14\SDK\BootstrapperCore.dll`